# how to set rails validates uniqueness on column hstore key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, rails-postgresql, hstore

I have a table `channels`, with an hstore column `credentials`.  The credentials for each channel might be different, but I want them to be unique when populated.  I have set some postgres indexes like this:

```
execute "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX channels_key_seller_id_values_unique ON channels((credentials -> 'seller_id'))"
execute "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX channels_key_auth_token_values_unique ON channels((credentials -> 'auth_token'))"
```

This correctly raises a hard error during @channel.save with `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`, however I would like the familiar rails way of displaying form errors.  What (if any) is the syntax of using validates uniqueness on hstore keys 'auth_token' and 'seller_id' ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it might help: https://gist.github.com/rf-/2322543

Notice that he used 'sqlite3'.

Comment: The gist mentions including ActiveModel::Validations. Unfortunately, the module does not support uniqueness. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html